# Grouping a column by boolean comparison (similar to using Matlab's grpstats)

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe in Pandas that has the following format (with a bunch of other columns as well)

```
   chip  WL     ok
0     1   1   True
1     1   2   True
2     1   3   True
3     1   4   True
4     2   1  False
5     2   2   True
6     2   3   True
7     2   4   True
```

I want to group by chip, count the number of WLs for each `chip`, and do a logical `and` on each value in the `ok` columns. The expected output should look like this:

```
   chip  WLs     ok
0     1   4    True
1     2   4   False
```

In Matlab, this would be achieved by using the following command:

```
a = grpstats(CellYield,{'chip'},{@all},'DataVars',{'ok'});
a.Properties.VarNames{2} = 'WLs';
a.Properties.VarNames{3} = 'ok';
```

Which would output a dataset like this:

```
chip WLs    ok
1    4      True
2    4      False
```

How do I do this in Python and Pandas?

Answer (score 3):

Use `groupby` and we can pass a dict of functions to apply to each column, for `WL` column we apply `count` from `pandas.Series`, the `all` applies a test on all values and returns `True` if all values in the series are `True` and `False` otherwise.

```
In [6]:

df.groupby('chip').agg({'WL':pd.Series.count, 'ok':all})

Out[6]:
      WL     ok
chip           
1      4   True
2      4  False

[2 rows x 2 columns]
```

**UPDATE**

In order to assign these values back to the original dataframe you can use `transform`, unfortunately I couldn't figure out how to apply different functions to different columns as transform won't accept `agg` function or a user defined function.

So you can instead do it in 2 passes like so:

```
In [30]:

df['WL'] = df.groupby('chip')['WL'].transform('count')
df['ok'] = df.groupby('chip')['ok'].transform('all')
df
Out[30]:
       chip  WL     ok    foo    bar
index                               
0         1   4   True  hello  world
1         1   4   True  hello  world
2         1   4   True  hello  world
3         1   4   True  hello  world
4         2   4  False  hello  world
5         2   4  False  hello  world
6         2   4  False  hello  world
7         2   4  False  hello  world

[8 rows x 5 columns]
```

Comment: Thanks, this works. 
Is there any way to pass along columns without any change in aggregate? For example, I have some additional columns containing strings. They are the same for all use cases. I want the output to have the columns [chip, wl, foo, bar, ok] where there is no change done to foo and bar. How can this be done? Foo and bar are the same for all entries.

Comment: sounds like you want `transform` this will return an object that is indexed same as the orig df, I don't know if it will accept `agg` functions, I cannot get that to work, maybe post as a different question specific to that requirement

Comment: @veor I found a way to do this by calling transform twice let me know if this answers your question and if so you can accept as an answer by clicking on the empty tick mark under the vote arrows